# VS2013 Source Control breaks references on initial pull

Tags: visual-studio-2013

At work, we're using VS2013 Online. We push our entire project folders to source control (via Team-Explorer and Source Control Explorer). When another person pulls the repository for the first time (or to a new location on their computer) it breaks all the references to non-native packages (such as EntityFramework). All of the packages and their dlls are in the Source Control (packages folder) and the projects are pulled as-is.

To fix this issue we have to go one-by-one to each reference and do a NuGet "Update-Package " for each one. It'll respond "No updates found" but fix the reference.

Is there any way around this? I feel like this shouldn't be happening so what're we doing wrong?

Comment: The "packages" folder is typically not checked in: http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the csproj file right before leaving work and it was looking at the lib folders which I realized weren't in the source control (but the packages folder was)